# React custom hooks value is not changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following simple react page using hooks

https://codesandbox.io/embed/funny-resonance-2ijv4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

which I extracted the selected value into a separate component so it can be accessed by other components. In the Header component the updated value is actually updated once user clicks on the ListGroup.Item but it's updated twice.  which I don't know why.

second, the value is not update in the App component. 
what am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the Header component the updated value is actually updated once user clicks on the ListGroup.Item but it's updated twice. which I don't know why.

Place your `console.log(selectedView);` in an effect and try it again.

> The value is not updated in the App component. What am I going wrong?

Each component also get's its own copy of the `useView` hook, it doesn't have any "global" state.

You can expose out an `onViewChange` handler prop on your `Header` component and use an effect to handle calling back with the current selected view.

```
const Header = ({ onViewChange }) => {
  const [selectedView, setSelectedView] = useView();

  useEffect(() => {
    onViewChange(selectedView);
  }, [onViewChange, selectedView]);
  ...
```

Add some state to `App` and save the called back view value

```
function App() {
  const [selectedView, setSelectedView] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // place console.log in effect so only logs once per update
    console.log(selectedView);
  }, [selectedView])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Logo />
            <Header onViewChange={setSelectedView} />
            {selectedView === VIEW.clients && <ClientsView />}
            {selectedView === VIEW.categories && <CategoriesView />}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit friendly-architecture-50puu]

Comment: I added a console.log outside an effect before the return statement and it prints twice.

Comment: so for global state I have to create a context instead yes? is that a common pattern?

Comment: @ArmenB Yes. Many app state management libraries are built on using the context system, but at the barest level you have a context provider with some value, and consumers anywhere further down the react tree. React even has a `useContext` hook.